# Python returns JSON with line breaks in RGBA coordinates

Tags: python, json

I'm working with python to produce json for semanticnet/OpenGraphiti. I've inserted RGBA coordinates as a list within a json object.

The result is that each RGBA point is printed on a separate line, which I've been fixing manually, as it can't be interpreted by OpenGraphiti in this format.

How do I return the coordinates on a single line within the object? (I don't need to have the entire object printed on one line, just the coordinates.)

Here's a sample of the code, along with the result I'm getting:

```
color = []
for i in range(len(hostname)):
    color.append([1.0, 1.0, 6.0, 1.0])

edges = zip(origin, hostname, connection, shortname, color)

Result:
    {
     "src": "oddjob", 
     "dst": "runloop", 
     "og:space:color": [
      1.0, 
      1.0, 
      6.0, 
      1.0
     ], 
     "type": "connection", 
     "id": "oddjob-runloop"
    }
```

Here's the result I need:

```
{
 "src": "oddjob", 
 "dst": "runloop", 
 "og:space:color": [1.0, 1.0, 6.0, 1.0], 
 "type": "connection", 
 "id": "oddjob-runloop"
}
```

Any help would be much appreciated!

Comment: Whitespace is not significant in JSON. Those two results are equivalent. Unless OpenGraphiti is using a broken JSON parser something else is going on. Does it really not work at first and then it does when you remove the newlines?

Comment: Yeah, it really doesn't work.

Comment: You should really post a bug report then.

Answer (score 0):

The Python `json` module doesn't give you this level of control, but you can construct the JSON semi-manually:

```
import json

result = {
    "src": "oddjob",
    "dst": "runloop",
    "og:space:color": [
        1.0,
        1.0,
        6.0,
        1.0
    ],
    "type": "connection",
    "id": "oddjob-runloop"
}

result = {k: json.dumps(v) for k, v in result.items()}
result = """{{
 "src": {src},
 "dst": {dst},
 "og:space:color": {color},
 "type": {type},
 "id": {id}
}}""".format(color=result["og:space:color"], **result)

print(result)
```

Output:

```
{
 "src": "oddjob",
 "dst": "runloop",
 "og:space:color": [1.0, 1.0, 6.0, 1.0],
 "type": "connection",
 "id": "oddjob-runloop"
}
```

Or you could use a regex to find and replace the array of numbers.